# Delete entire line if a specific word is longer than X characters, words in the row delimited by comma

Tags: awk, sed, notepad++

I have a .sql file with more than 1000000 rows.
I need to delete the rows that contains more than X characters on the third 'column' ( The columns are separated by comma )

I tried using some VI, SED and AWK.
Also Notepad++ but did'nt succeed in any of those

```
(255500, 0, '0093', 0.4350, 0.4350 ) - Keep this
(255501, 0, '0035521160', 0.4350, 0.4350 ) < - Delete this
```

The words on the third column delimited by comma that contain less than 8 characters i wanna keep the row, the ones that are longer than 8 i need to delete the entire row.

I tried deleting manually but there is too many rows

Comment: Does your file really look like that? Please edit your question to show how exactly your file looks like

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far, however inadequate, and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: You mentioned @Raul Chiarella that you have tried few things, we always encourage people to post their efforts in their post so please do add them(along with answering questions asked in comments by users) and let us know then.

Comment: `awk -F'[ ,]+' '(length($3)-2)<8' filename` may be what you're looking for.  But your input file doesn't actually seem to follow a pattern. For instance you've  no delimiters between the opening parenthesis and the first field, but, you have one between the last field and closing parenthesis.

Comment: This looks like part of a SQL INSERT statement, so to those that are asking, "Yes, this is probably what it looks like". Strings will be encapsulated with single quotes. Raul, should this only be for lines that start with a parentheses (or any other rules)? Otherwise, could you insert all of this into a different table, then filter out afterwards? Surely that would be more reasonable.

Comment: Also, is this the only INSERT statement in this file? If so, splitting on `'` in awk would probably be easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this isn't all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output:

```
$ awk -F, 'length($3)<8' file
(255500, 0, '0093', 0.4350, 0.4350 ) - Keep this
```

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed:

```
sed -E '/^[^,]+,[^,]+,\s*[^,]{9,}/d' d
```

add -i option to truly edit it; `sed -Ei`...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

Search: `^[^,]+,[^,]+,\s*'[^']{8,}'.*\R?`

Replace by: `(nothing)`

It should work even when adding spaces between column data:

```
(255501, 0,          '12345678', 0.4350, 0.4350 )
```

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/xuXvUF/2/)